# TeamCity VS plugin - error Failed to collect pending changes in Subversion

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2013, tortoisesvn, teamcity

I've updated my Ankhsvn, TortoiseSVN and my SlikSVN to the latest version and now, after I open the solution in visual studio and try to remote run my changes I have the following error:

"Failed to collect pending changes in Subversion.

Error: Opened solution contains no Subversion versioned resources"

My current versions are: TeamCity Addin 8.1, AnkhSvn 2.5.12478, TortoiseSVN 1.8.8.25755 and SlikSVN 1.8.10, the x64 versions.

Using TurtoiseSVN in Windows Explorer works, but I want to be able to use the TeamCity plugin inside VS. The plugin is configured to use the SlikSVN, the correct path is specified. Could someone give some advise on this? Thanks!

Comment: Please [report problem](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/Feedback), e.g. [create issue in tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=TW&clearDraft=true&c=Subsystem+IDE%3A+VS+add-in)

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve this, as a workaround, I had to go to TeamCity menu option in VS, then Options, then Source Control, Subversion and for "Search Changes in" had to change it from "Automatically detect directories" to "Manually specified directories" and add my local directories, the ones where my code is.